# How to export single API request with body in Postman so it can be imported

Tags: postman, export

Postman can export whole collections, and also single requests.

I'd like to export just one request, so I can send it as an example to somebody else who can import it in their Postman via (possible Raw Text?):

[image]

Normally, I'd use cURL format which is supported even for imports within Postman. But there's also [issue #7895](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/7895) that seems to block this option or to be more precise, it won't import request body, which is exactly what I need at the moment.

When I go into a request in Postman => code, there are many options, but it seems that the only option also suitable for imports is cURL. Postman can't import requests written in a programming/scripting language, so all other options here are out of the question (yes, I've tried HTTP, but that's not a supported format for imports either).

Having said that, is there a way I can import a single request with body data in Postman?

My Postman version is 7.16.0 (x64) for Windows OS.

Comment: Couldn't you just create a new collection folder and create a copy of the request you need to that folder and share it.

Comment: @PDHide: I think this is an option, probably the only one at the moment. I think I'll do it if I don't find a way to just grab some text I can send in chat on slack.

Comment: Exporting collection with one request generates json file, which can be imported by other user. That's the proper way to do it.

Comment: It seems like new issue so you could probably use import in old version of postman.

Comment: @pavelsaman The issue you mentioned has been fixed in the latest version of the app.

Comment: @DannyDainton: good news, thank you for letting me know

Comment: @pavelsaman or @ DannyDainton - As you guys stated the issue has been fixed in the latest version. Can any of you answer the question with more details? It would be helpful for others in future.

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct option to export a single request from Postman.

You can create and export collections. Here is a link to help with that.
https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/importing-and-exporting-data/#exporting-collections

Regarding the single request thing, you can try a workaround. **I tried with the RAW body parameters and it worked.**

What you can do is,

1. In your request tab, click on the 3 dots in the top right corner of your request panel/box.
   [image]
2. Select Code. This will open Generate Code Snippents window.
   [image]
3. Copy the cURL code and save it in a text file. Share this with who you want to.
   [image]
4. They can then import the request from the text file.
   [image]

Comment: This helped me a lot. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a shared workspace, you can copy a link to take the other person directly to the request. The option to do so is to the right of the request name edit option.
[image: Image of a Postman request with the link to copy a request displayed]

Answer (score 0):

You may create a shared workspace with your team members to share the API request without going through import and export.

More details on how to create a workspace and team can be found here https://learning.postman.com/docs/collaborating-in-postman/collaboration-intro/